# Active model - set attributes of parent object based on child attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have two models like this

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, allow_destroy: true

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
```

In the db of Cart, I have a column Total Price, and for each book I have a price.

How do I automatically update the total price of cart, when I set the price for each book?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating instances of `Book` only when they are added onto carts, you can do

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart

  after_initialize :update_cart_total

  private
    def update_cart_total
      self.cart.total_price += price
      self.cart.save
    end
end
```

This will call the `update_cart_total` method whenever an instance of `Book` is created.